# how to use vbulletin variables globally?

Tags: php, variables, vbulletin

I want to use {vb:raw human_verify} on another page inside vbulletin ?

When i use this variable in another template , it does not work.

It works perfectly on the some templates (register, search, ..) but never work in another template..

I have tried to add new plugin which make vars global :

```
vB_Template::preRegister('activity_home',array('includedphp ' => $includedphp));
```

BUT this works only on new (custom) vbulletin vb:raw variables.

How to overcome this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I assume your using vb4 and your variable is set in includedphp.
Then you need to change :

> activity_home

With the name of the template where you need to use the variable (do it multiple times if you want to add it in several templates). So basicaly : use "FORUMHOME" to put it into your forum home or "header" to put it on the header...

[This link](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=228078) could be helpful (see "Save into an array and preregister to use in an existing/stock template" section ).
Hope that helps.

EDIT :

```
$templater = vB_Template::create('mytemplate'); // Define a template
$templater->register('my_var', $my_var); // define some variables
$templater->register('my_array', $my_array);
$templatevalues['my_insertvar'] = $templater->render(); // Save the template into a variable, "note that the data needs to be saved into an array a simple variable will throw an error"
vB_Template::preRegister('FORUMHOME', $templatevalues);  // "insert" your variable into the FORUMHOME template
```

Then you can add the new template in FORUMHOME template with that line :

```
{vb:raw my_insertvar}
```

Comment: I know this article but didn't notice that it includes existing templates too. But i cannot view code blocks. Could you copy it here please?

Answer (score 1):

I just wrestled with this for far too long... that example is just terrible.  No fault of Niak's.  I feel the original author wasn't very clear on how to register simple variables to existing templates.

I literally copy/pasted the example above into a Plugin, set $my_var to "test" and `{vb:raw my_insertvar}` in the `FORUMHOME` template just wouldn't work.  Here's the code I initially tried:

```
$my_var = "test";

$templater = vB_Template::create('mytemplate'); // Define a template
$templater->register('my_var', $my_var); // define some variables
$templatevalues['my_insertvar'] = $templater->render();
vB_Template::preRegister('FORUMHOME', $templatevalues);
```

Please, if anyone knows what I am doing wrong in not being able to access the value of `my_var` in the original example, let me know!  I can not get that to work for the life of me.  It keeps just spitting out `<!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE: mytemplate --><!-- END TEMPLATE: mytemplate -->`.

=============================== WORKING EXAMPLE ===============================

Then, I found a better example.  It turns out  you only need two lines for this to work:

1. Go to `Plugins & Products` > `Plugin Manager`.
2. Scroll to the bottom, and click `[Add New Plugin]`
3. The hook I chose is **`global_bootstrap_init_start`**
4. Insert the following two lines (**`navbar`** is the template that I'm registering `testVar_output` to):

   > ```
   > $testVar = "This is a test.";
   >
   > vB_Template::preRegister('navbar',array('testVar_output' => $testVar));
   > ```
5. Place this code in **`navbar`**:

   > {vb:raw testVar_output}
6. Note that the `vb:raw` variable name is the value on the **LEFT** in the `array()`.
7. There seems to be no need to use the `$templater->render()` function for preregistering variables, despite all the examples that I've seen that say you need it.  Just register the variable, and use the variable! It's that simple!
8. I realize that this does not allow for template caching, which is why I'm so concerned that I can't get the original example working... (help!?)

Comment: I can only assume since `navbar` is a built-in template, that it's cached, and this variable will be cached along with it, so no need to create my own template and then cache it...  is that a faulty assumption?